# Cheaper way to duplicate image n times with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

In [my productivity app](https://complice.co/) there's a log of how many pomodoros you did each day. This is then displayed for each day on your timeline, with a little tomato icon for each pomodoro. I'm using `ng-repeat` for each day, and then `ng-repeat` for the images, as shown here:

```
<img ng-repeat="p in range(day.pomosDone) track by $index" src='/img/pomodoro.png'>
```

(The range function is just this: `$scope.range = function(n) {return new Array(n)}`)

This works totally fine, except that with users who have dozens of pomodoros each day, it's really slow to load (particularly in firefox, it seems). This kind of makes sense.

I can think of lots of other ways to do this (including cheating and using jQuery) but none of them seem particularly elegant or natural. It mostly doesn't need to change after loading, although I guess it might want to in the future if the user updates their data. But I can retrigger that.

Comment: when asking question you re expected to provide minimal example, not link to your site... <img ng-repeat just works at ~ same speed as usual image tag and can not be optimised in general. (Of course you should remove function, but this shouldnt help)

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to repeat a few dozen images when users have that many activities?  That sounds like a lot of clutter.  I think maybe this problem is a symptom of a design/UI problem.  And a redesign will solve the angular problem.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Nah I think it makes sense as a visual quantity. A sort of discrete bar graph. I feel good about the design.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert the `<img>` icon to being css based such as: `<span class="tomato-icon"></span>` so it will only incur one image request no matter how many you have.

CSS would be something like:

```
.tomato-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background: url(path to your tomato icon) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: If you put ten img tags on page with same url - browser will send 1 request anyway.

Comment: This is true if proper headers are set for server caching.